# How to transform my column values that are lists of dictionaries to new columns in my pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, normalize

Here is my pd.DataFrame with its `metadata` column:

```
      date           metadata
0     2022-12-03     [{'key': 'key1', 'value': value0.1'}, {'key': 'key2', 'value': value0.2'}, {'key': 'key3', 'value': value0.3'}]
1     2022-12-07     [{'key': 'key1', 'value': value1.1'}, {'key': 'key2', 'value': value1.2'}, {'key': 'key3', 'value': value1.3'}]
2     2022-12-02     [{'key': 'key1', 'value': value2.1'}, {'key': 'key2', 'value': value2.2'}, {'key': 'key3', 'value': value2.3'}]
3     2022-12-01     [{'key': 'key1', 'value': value3.1'}, {'key': 'key2', 'value': value3.2'}, {'key': 'key3', 'value': value3.3'}]
```

What can I do so it becomes:

```
      date           key1         key2         key3
0     2022-12-03     value0.1     value0.2     value0.3
1     2022-12-07     value1.1     value1.2     value1.3
2     2022-12-02     value2.1     value2.2     value2.3
3     2022-12-01     value3.1     value3.2     value3.3
```

**Edit:**

I don't know the names of the keys neither their number.

Answer (score 1):

You can also - although this is not very efficient - obtain a df from the metadata in each row and subsequently use pivot to obtain a long-to-wide transformation:

```
df_list = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    d = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[i,]["metadata"])
    d["ID"] = i
    df_list.append(d)
d_all = pd.concat(df_list)
d_all.pivot(index="ID",columns="key", values="value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list with nested dict comprehension for extract keys and values of dictionaries, pass to `DataFrame` and append to original DataFrame, [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for remove column after processing:

```
import ast

#if necessary
#df['metadata'] = df['metadata'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{y['key']:y['value'] for y in x} for x in df.pop('metadata')], 
                   index=df.index)
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
         date      key1      key2      key3
0  2022-12-03  value0.1  value0.2  value0.3
1  2022-12-07  value1.1  value1.2  value1.3
2  2022-12-02  value2.1  value2.2  value2.3
3  2022-12-01  value3.1  value3.2  value3.3
```

If always 2 values of dictionary for each list use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([dict(y.values() for y in x) for x in df.pop('metadata')], 
                   index=df.index)
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
         date      key1      key2      key3
0  2022-12-03  value0.1  value0.2  value0.3
1  2022-12-07  value1.1  value1.2  value1.3
2  2022-12-02  value2.1  value2.2  value2.3
3  2022-12-01  value3.1  value3.2  value3.3
```

EDIT: Final solution, `df.index` is not necessary if default `RangeIndex`:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([{y['key']: y['value'] for y in x} for x in df.pop('metadata')]))
```

Comment: This is fine but imagine my keys to be multiple, I don't know how much of them I'm going to get or what are there names

Comment: @DamienTanneau - answer was edited, only necessary in each nested dict 2 elements key + value, keys names are not important.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I modified it a bit and did: `df  = df.join(pd.DataFrame([{y['key']: y['value'] for y in x["attributes"]} for x in df.pop('metadata')]))` which works great

Comment: Please modify `x["attributes"]` to `x` in your edit :) I can't do it in my comment.

`df  = df.join(pd.DataFrame([{y['key']: y['value'] for y in x} for x in df.pop('metadata')]))`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) on the Series after [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
s = df.pop('metadata').explode()

df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(s).set_index(s.index)
               .pivot(columns='key', values='value'))
```

Output:

```
         date      key1      key2      key3
0  2022-12-03  value0.1  value0.2  value0.3
1  2022-12-07  value1.1  value1.2  value1.3
2  2022-12-02  value2.1  value2.2  value2.3
3  2022-12-01  value3.1  value3.2  value3.3
```